# How overwrite a function of a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I want to overwrite a function of a jQuery plugin. I instantiate the plugin in this way:
`new jQuery.NameOfPlugin('someId')` and the plugin is declared as

```
$.NameOfPlugin= function() {

        var create=function() {
            ...
        }
}
```

I would like to overwrite, for example, the `var create` and use an other function, without modify the original plugin.

How I can do this?

Comment: You can only override what you access to from the outside. `create` is local to the plugin so you cannot override it. You have find an other way.